# Sending off an image name with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image-processing, html5-canvas

I have a canvas drawing that can be saved, however when i use ajax i only can send the data string and the name that i send with it is not picked up, can someone help me tell as to why the name isn't being picked up, is it a problem with my javascript or php?

Here is the ajax javascript

```
var save_name = document.getElementById('save_name').value;

document.getElementById('imagebox').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('imageoverlay').style.display = "none";
var Drawing = document.getElementById('canvas');
var drawingString = Drawing.toDataURL("image/png");
var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

var name = "potato";
ajax.open("POST",'save_image.php',true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(ajax.readyState == 4){
        alert("image saved");
    }
}
ajax.send(postData+"name="+save_name);
```

And here is the php

```
if(isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $rawImage = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
    $removeHeaders = substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
    $decode = base64_decode($removeHeaders);
    $fopen = fopen('user/'.$log_username.'/'.$name.'.png', 'wb');
    fwrite($fopen, $decode);
    fclose($fopen);
}
```

The code works, but it just doesnt pick the name up so it saves the image as nothing just .png

Comment: you need a `&` on `name=` so its like `postData+"&name="+save_name`

Comment: i changed it to this but unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

First told PHP that your data is not encoded using either of the standard encodings for form data:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
```

PHP doesn't know how to parse `canvas/upload` data, so it won't populate `$_POST`.

If you want to populate `$_POST` you need to specify one of those formats. The one closest to the format you are using is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Second, you have changed your variable name from `name` to `save_name` half way through writing the code. You need to be consistent.

Third, your data isn't properly encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. You need to:

1. Separate each key/value pair with a `&` character
2. Escape any characters with special meaning

Such:

```
var postData = "canvasData=" + encodeURIComponent(drawingString) + 
        "&" + "name=" + encodeURIComponent(save_name);
```

Fourth, you are trying to parse the raw HTTP POST data, but PHP can decode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for you. Just use `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['canvasData']`.

Comment: I have tried this, however it now says that i have errors with the picture when i try to open it, is the code that you would have user? ill post the ajax and php separtly so they dont all come in one block

Comment: $name = $_POST['name'];
 $canvas = $_POST['canvasData'].
 
 $fopen = fopen('user/'.$log_username.'/'.$name.'.png', 'wb');
 fwrite($fopen, $canvas);
 fclose($fopen);

Comment: var drawingString = Drawing.toDataURL("image/png");
         
         var postData = "canvasData=" + encodeURIComponent(drawingString) + 
        "&" + "name=" + encodeURIComponent(save_name);
         var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = "potato";
         ajax.open("POST",'save_image.php',true);
         ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
         ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
          if(ajax.readyState == 4){
           alert("image saved");
          }
         }
         ajax.send(postData);

Comment: You are writing the `data:` URI directly to the file instead of stripping off the content type and encoding and running the rest through `base64_decode` as you did before.

Comment: And you never give `save_name` a value, nor use the `name` variable.

Comment: $name = $_POST['name'];
 $canvas = $_POST['canvasData'].
 $rawImage = $canvas;
 $removeHeaders = substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
 $decode = base64_decode($removeHeaders);
 $fopen = fopen('user/'.$log_username.'/'.$name.'.png', 'wb');
 fwrite($fopen, $decode);
 fclose($fopen);

Comment: This is the code that i have now used and it is still giving me errors

Comment: save_name has got a value its given earlier on i couldnt fit that bit in the comment, thats not the [roblem that bit is working it just doesnt like the image bit now :D

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with that, I'd look at the raw data at each stage of the process and see if it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys :D i have done it with your help

var save_name = document.getElementById('save_name').value;

```
            document.getElementById('imagebox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('imageoverlay').style.display = "none";
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

                    var imageoverlay = document.getElementById('imagesaveoverlay');
                        var imagebox = document.getElementById('imagesavebox');
                        var save_box_name = document.getElementById('save_box_name');
                        var ok_saved = document.getElementById('ok_saved');
                    var close_imagesave = document.getElementById('close_imagesave');

                    save_box_name.innerHTML = save_name;
                    imagesaveoverlay.style.display = "block";
                        imagesaveoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
                    imagesavebox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
                    imagesavebox.style.top = "100px";
                    imagesavebox.style.display = "block";

                    close_imagesave.addEventListener('click', function () {

                                 document.getElementById('imagesavebox').style.display = "none";
                         document.getElementById('imagesaveoverlay').style.display = "none";
                        });  
                    ok_saved.addEventListener('click', function () {

                                 document.getElementById('imagesavebox').style.display = "none";
                         document.getElementById('imagesaveoverlay').style.display = "none";
                        }); 


                }

            }
            ajax.open("POST", "save_image.php", true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajax.send("img="+data+"&name="+save_name);
```

And the php is this :D

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
    $data = $_POST['img'];

    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
    $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
    $img= base64_decode($data);

    $path = 'user/'.$log_username.'/'.$name.'.png';
    if(file_put_contents($path, $img)){
        print $path;

    }else{
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    }
```